# Compare two generic type in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm developing an c# dll library which apply dynamic linq query.
I'v defined a generic interface and a generic date type like below:

```
public interface IRangeValue<T> where T : struct
{
    Nullable<T> GetHigh();
    Nullable<T> GetLow();
    void SetHigh(Nullable<T> val);
    void SetLow(Nullable<T> val);

}

public class RangeT<T> : IRangeValue<T>
    where T :struct
{
    public Nullable<T> High { get; set; }
    public Nullable<T> Low { get; set; }
    public Nullable<T> GetHigh() { return High; }
    public Nullable<T> GetLow() { return Low; }
    public void SetHigh(Nullable<T> val) { High = val; }
    public void SetLow(Nullable<T> val) { Low = val; }
}
```

Then I use the generic date type in my code like below:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> RangeCompare<T>(Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> selector, RangeT<DateTime> patten)
            {
                Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
                if (patten.GetHigh().HasValue)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => selector.Compile()(s) <= patten.GetHigh().Value);
                }
                if (patten.GetLow().HasValue)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => selector.Compile()(s).Equals(patten.GetLow().Value));
                }
                return predicate;
            }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> RangeCompare<T>(Expression<Func<T, int>> selector, RangeT<int> patten)
            {
                Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
                if (patten.GetHigh().HasValue)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => selector.Compile()(s) <= patten.GetHigh().Value);
                }
                if (patten.GetLow().HasValue)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => selector.Compile()(s) >= patten.GetLow().Value);
                }
                return predicate;
            }
```

Actually, the body of the two methods is same if I ignore the input type. So I try to write a new generic method to replace the two methods. The new method like below:

```
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> RangeCompare<T>(Expression<Func<T, K>> selector, IRangeValue<K> patten)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
        if (patten.GetHigh().HasValue)
        {
            predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => selector.Compile()(s) <= patten.GetHigh().Value);
        }
        if (patten.GetLow().HasValue)
        {
            predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => selector.Compile()(s) >= patten.GetLow().Value);
        }
        return predicate;
    }
```

I replaced the param RangeT(RangeT) with IRangeValue.
Now compiler told me the operators like '<=', '>=' error, because can't infer the generic type K

So my question is : Is there any way I can realize the generic method?

Comment: Why not just define the properties in the interface instead of get and set methods?

Comment: I believe you want to use `Expression.LessThanOrEqual` and `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual`.

Comment: Don't you need `RangeCompare` to have a `K` generic type parameter? Why are you passing `selector` in as an `Expression<Func<>>` instead of just a `Func<>` if you are going to just call `Compile()` anyway?

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL or EF or is this all LINQ to Objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with LINQ to Objects, the standard way to handle generic comparisons is to use the `Comparer` class.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> RangeCompare<T, K>(Func<T, K> selector, IRangeValue<K> patten) where K : struct {
    var cmp = Comparer<K>.Default;

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
    if (patten.GetHigh().HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => cmp.Compare(selector(s), patten.GetHigh().Value) <= 0);
    if (patten.GetLow().HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And<T>(s => cmp.Compare(selector(s), patten.GetLow().Value) >= 0);

    return predicate;
}
```

Note: I changed the method to take `Func` so you don't need the call to `Compile`.